# NewComputerModern Boldface and Smallcaps in German Language

Tags: luatex, fontspec, polyglossia, newcomputermodern, fontsetup

I am loading NCM (New Computer Modern) with

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%           Font 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setmainfont{NewCM10-Book.otf}  % Ligatures: bei newfontface definiert

% Get Ligatures for NCM in german!
\newfontface\germanfont{NewCM10-Book.otf}[%
    Script=Latin,
    Language=Default,
    Ligatures={Common},
    ItalicFont=NewCM10-BookItalic.otf,%
    BoldFont=NewCM10-Bold.otf,%
    BoldItalicFont=NewCM10-BoldItalic.otf,%
    SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}
]

\setsansfont{NewCMSans10-Book.otf}[%
ItalicFont=NewCMSans10-Oblique.otf,%
BoldFont=NewCMSans10-Bold.otf,%
BoldItalicFont=NewCMSans10-BoldOblique.otf,%
SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}]

\setmonofont{NewCMMono10-Book.otf}[%
ItalicFont=NewCMMono10-Italic.otf,%
BoldFont=NewCMMono10-Bold.otf,%
BoldItalicFont=NewCMMono10-BoldOblique.otf,%
SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}]

\begin{document}
    \textbf{\textsc{Text}}
\end{document}
```

and I am not sure, why I do not get bold small caps.

What do I need to add so that I can use `\textbf{\textsc{Text}}` in my documents?
Currently I only seem to be getting bold text.

[image: Text]

### **UPDATE**

It seems to be a problem with `polyglossia`.
If I use the package provided for `NewCM` called `fontsetup` which is basically the same as `\setmainfont{…}, …` for `NewCM` I managed to get small caps and bold small caps without `polyglossia`.

Only when loading `polyglossia` it breaks again…

Example without `polyglossia`:
[image: without polyglossia]

### **UPDATE 2**

I have switched to `babel` now, which seems to be working like a charm without any problem.

Comment: The New Computer Modern fonts probably only have small caps in the Regular styles, i.e., Bold small caps don’t exist.

Comment: New Computer Modern *have* small caps in bold face, try to run `optex` to the file: `\fontfam[newcm] \caps\bf Text. \bye`

Comment: @wipet Huh... Then the problem is most certainly how the OP sets up the font.

Comment: Why `\setmainfont{NewCM10-Book.otf}` then `\newfontface\germanfont{NewCM10-Book.otf}[...]`? The two setups include almost the exact same `Script`, `Language` and `Ligatures` settings (btw, you probably want `Ligatures={Common,TeX}`). A single `\setmainfont{NewCM10-Book.otf}[ItalicFont=...,BoldFont=...,...]` should work. You probably also need `SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,Numbers=OldStyle}`.

Comment: @RuixiZhang I needed the `\newfontface\germanfont{…}` because of a bug previously. The ligatures were not working for german if I was using `polyglossia`. But I'll try that. 

My previous question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631464/fontspec-and-polyglossia-in-german-turns-off-ligatures-in-ncm-newcomputermodern

Comment: You probably do not need `Ligatures=Common`, or a separate `\germanfont`. By default, `fontspec` (and therefore `polyglossia`) adds `Ligatures=Common` to `\setmainfont` and `\setsandfont`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few intersecting problems here.  The first is that, when you load `NewCM10`, LaTeX looks for the file `NewCM10.fontspec`.  This only declares bold and italic faces within a `SizeFeatures=` block, which confuses `polyglossia` into not being able to find the bold font.  The solution to that is to copy and paste the contents of the `.fontspec` file, adding a fallback:

```
\defaultfontfeatures[NewCM10-Book]
   {
    Extension = .otf ,
    Font = NewCM10-Book,
    ItalicFont=NewCM10-BookItalic,%
    BoldFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
    BoldItalicFont=NewCM10-BoldItalic,%
    SlantedFont=NewCM10-Book,%
    BoldSlantedFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
    SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle},
    SizeFeatures={%
            {Size=-8, Font=NewCM08-Book,
                    ItalicFont=NewCM08-BookItalic,%
                    BoldFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
                    BoldItalicFont=NewCM10-BoldItalic,%
                    SlantedFont=NewCM08-Book,%
                    BoldSlantedFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
                    SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}},
            {Size=8, Font=NewCM08-Book,
                    ItalicFont=NewCM08-BookItalic,%
                    BoldFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
                    BoldItalicFont=NewCM10-BoldItalic,%
                    SlantedFont=NewCM08-Book,%
                    BoldSlantedFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
                    SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}},
          {Size= 9-, Font = NewCM10-Book,
                    ItalicFont=NewCM10-BookItalic,%
                    BoldFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
                    BoldItalicFont=NewCM10-BoldItalic,%
                    SlantedFont=NewCM10-Book,%
                    BoldSlantedFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
                    SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}}%
    }}
```

Having done that, you can now load the font as your main font:

```
\setmainfont{NewCM10-Book}  % Ligatures: bei newfontface definiert
```

The font does provide `Language=German`, **but it is broken.**  You could therefore also load,

```
\newfontfamily\germanfont{NewCM10-Book}[Language=German]
```

But, if you do this, the font file does not enable the small-caps feature with `Language=German`, so it will simply break.  With `Language=Default`, the `\textsc` command will follow traditional orthography, rather than giving you a *Großes Eszett*.

This, inclidentally, means that someone using `babel` to set New Computer Modern as the German font needs to, in addition to the extra setup above, override the automatic language selection with something like `\babelfont[german]{rm}[Language=Default]{NewCM10-Book}`.

#### The MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%           Font 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\defaultfontfeatures[NewCM10-Book]
   {
    Extension = .otf ,
    Font = NewCM10-Book,
    ItalicFont=NewCM10-BookItalic,%
    BoldFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
    BoldItalicFont=NewCM10-BoldItalic,%
    SlantedFont=NewCM10-Book,%
    BoldSlantedFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
    SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle},
    SizeFeatures={%
            {Size=-8, Font=NewCM08-Book,
                    ItalicFont=NewCM08-BookItalic,%
                    BoldFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
                    BoldItalicFont=NewCM10-BoldItalic,%
                    SlantedFont=NewCM08-Book,%
                    BoldSlantedFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
                    SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}},
            {Size=8, Font=NewCM08-Book,
                    ItalicFont=NewCM08-BookItalic,%
                    BoldFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
                    BoldItalicFont=NewCM10-BoldItalic,%
                    SlantedFont=NewCM08-Book,%
                    BoldSlantedFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
                    SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}},
          {Size= 9-, Font = NewCM10-Book,
                    ItalicFont=NewCM10-BookItalic,%
                    BoldFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
                    BoldItalicFont=NewCM10-BoldItalic,%
                    SlantedFont=NewCM10-Book,%
                    BoldSlantedFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
                    SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}}%
    }}


\setmainfont{NewCM10-Book}  % Ligatures: bei newfontface definiert

\begin{document}
    \noindent\textbf{\textsc{Frauenfußball}} \\
    \textsc{Frauenfußball} \\
    \textbf{Frauenfußball}
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern sample]

if you also want this to work for sans-serif and monospace, you need to do something similar with `NewCMMono10-Book` and `NewCMSans10-Book`.

What if you really want the *Großes Eszett*?  If you don’t want to be pragmatic and switch to some other font that makes this substitution, I did write [some code back in 2020](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/fake-small-caps-with-xetex-fontspec/444453#444453) that could be adapted to capitalize using the `de-alt` rules and rescale to get an `\ersatzsc` command.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot for your answer. 

To be quite honest I did not want to have these extravagant features and settings in order to enable `textsc` for my document. I was just trying to write a german document in `NCM` and needed bold, sc for my `labelfont` in my captions. I have thus switched to `babel` as I wrote in Update 2. 

It is nice to see that it is possible to modify the settings in `fontspec` and in `polyglossia` a lot. Although I do not find this particularly "user-friendly". How did you find out about all of this?

Comment: @MartinDagleish Well, you *shouldn’t* have to go through all that rigmarole just to use `\textsc` with Polyglossia. What I entered is what the `NewCM10-Book.fontspec` file really ought to say. Then you could just `\setmainfont{NewCM10-Book}`, and it would just work. Alternatively, `fontspec` could be rewritten to work with the file that’s out there.

Comment: @MartinDagleish I don’t know how helpful this is to you, but I heard that `fontspec` now looks for a `.fontspec` file from a presentation by Will Robertson in 2018, and from there it was a matter of searching for the filename and checking what it says. I found out about the missing small-caps feature for German by checking `otfinfo --script=latn.DEU -f` on the font file.

Comment: Ok thank you! That's amazing. I would have never found out about all of this! I appreciate you taking the time to explain all of this! :)